# Using NFS filesystem on embedded board

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am using NFS to mount filesystem on my embedded board. Filesystem is mounted via eth0
port on my board. But after filesystem is mounted, if i unplug network cable from eth0 and plug into eth1, NFS filesystem does not remount and target hangs until i plug cable into eth0 again. Is it a default NFS behaviour? Or a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket that NFS runs over is bound to the interface, hence it stops working if you yank the cable even if another interface would allow you to connect to the same network. If you want interface failover to work, you need to look into bonding eth0 and eth1. See http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: Another confusion :(
if i assign ip to eth1 and then unplug cable from eth0 and connect cable to eth1, then pinging eth1 does not work. Now NFS filesystem is disconnected but why ping to eth1 does not work since kernel is running? Thanks for help :)